# AGPBI Error, Resource Anim Not Found In Styles

Tags: android, apk

I'm trying to release signed APK of my project. But I am getting AGPBI error while building it. When I run it on my device or emulators, the project runs normally without any error. My targeted SDK version is same as the installed SDK.

This is the error I am getting when I try to build signed APK.

```
 org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:512)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:249)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor354.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file processing failed, see logs for details
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.QueuedResourceProcessor.waitForAll(QueuedResourceProcessor.java:121)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.QueuedResourceProcessor.end(QueuedResourceProcessor.java:141)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.close(QueueableAapt2.java:104)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:293)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:809)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:797)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:491)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractAapt.link(AbstractAapt.java:34)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:807)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:443)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:395)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:312)
    at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)
```

When i run assembleRelease, this is the error i get.

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: resource anim/anim_fragment_in (aka com.xxx.xxx.xxx:anim/anim_fragment_in) not found.","sources":[{"file":"D:\\Android Project\\MyProject\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles.xml"}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: resource anim/anim_fragment_out (aka com.xxx.xxx.xxx:anim/anim_fragment_out) not found.","sources":[{"file":"D:\\Android Project\\MyProject\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles.xml"}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
:app:processReleaseResources
error: failed linking references.
:app:processReleaseResources FAILED
```

It says animation not found in styles.xml, this is my styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseTheme" />


<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccentLight</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/grey_hard</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Toolbar.Light" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/grey_very_hard</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/grey_very_hard</item>
</style>

<style name="RippleStyleWhite">
    <item name="mrl_rippleOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="mrl_rippleColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="mrl_rippleHover">true</item>
    <item name="mrl_rippleAlpha">0.2</item>
</style>

<style name="RippleStyleBlack" parent="RippleStyleWhite">
    <item name="mrl_rippleColor">#96989A</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTabTextAppearance" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomRatingBar" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Indicator">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimaryLight</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/grey_hard</item>
</style>

<style name="EditText.Accent" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/grey_very_hard</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Primary" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="FragmentAnimation" parent="@style/AppTheme">

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.FullScreenDialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/Animation.WindowSlideUpDown</item>
</style>

<style name="Animation.WindowSlideUpDown" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/anim_fragment_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/anim_fragment_out</item>
</style>

<style name="mySwitch" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- active thumb & track color (30% transparency) -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>

    <!-- inactive thumb color -->
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#757575</item>

    <!-- inactive track color (30% transparency) -->
    <item name="android:colorForeground">#757575</item>
</style>
```

And here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx.xxxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig getSigningConfig()
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all {
                    def appName = "Xxxx Xxxxx Xxxx"
                    if (outputFileName != null && outputFileName.endsWith('.apk')) {
                        outputFileName = appName + " " + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'

    //Library Google Map
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.api.client:google-api-client-util:1.2.3-alpha'
    implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.15'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I have my anim_fragment files in res/anim/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, the problem is the anim xml files is in debug folder. Copy them to main folder fixed it.